# c# speech recognized how to get to the rest of the words after specific word

Tags: c#

I struggling for searching keyword by speech.
I want to get search keyword by getting AFTER specific words.

Speak statement = banana color is yellow

Specific words, "banana color is ".
Result should get "yellow".

```
SpeechSynthesizer SS = new SpeechSynthesizer
PromptBuilder Pb = new PromptBuilder();
SpeechRecognitionEngine re = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
Choices list = new Choices();
list.Add(news string[]{"banana color is "});
switch (e.Result.Text.To String()){
case "banana color is":
//I want it to display in textbox
//search Textbox.Append Text();
break;
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `String.Split`

var split =  e.Result.Text.Split(list[0]);

this way you'll get back a string[] containing the splitted result.

```
split[0] = list[0]
split[1] = // the remaining text
```

Comment: i cant make it. i made it in new event to handle the speech, cannot use list from there.
' void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)'
switch (e.Result.Text.ToString()) { 
                case "banana color is":
                    //result
                    break;
            }

i still cannot make it

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same, you can see a resolution at the bottom. Overall i have to say SpeechRecognitionEngine is kinda bad with free speech

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine h = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Choices commands = new Choices();
    commands.Add(new string[] { "command one", "command two", "Dictate" });

    GrammarBuilder gbuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
    gbuilder.Append(commands);
    gbuilder.AppendDictation();

    Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gbuilder);

    h.LoadGrammar(grammar);
    h.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    h.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;

    h.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    s.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult);

    s.SpeakAsync("Wie kann ich dir helfen");
}

void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Result.Text.StartsWith("command one"))
    {
    s.SpeakAsync("Command one");
    }
    else if (e.Result.Text.StartsWith("wie spät ist es"))
    {
        s.SpeakAsync("Command two");
    }
    else if (e.Result.Text.StartsWith("Dictate"))
    {
        s.SpeakAsync(e.Result.Dictate);
        lbl_ans.Text = e.Result.Text; //gets all text till you stoped talking
    }

}
```